# Azure Logic App - Copy from SharePoint Online to Azure Web App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am not able to figure out how to copy files from a SharePoint Online Document Library to an Azure Web App folder using Logic App. The requirements are as follows:

In SharePoint Library - Trigger: When a file is created or modified

Action: Copy the created or modified file to a selected folder in Azure Web App (overwrite if already exists)

What is the best approach?

Can I use Azure Web App's ftps connections?

Use Case:
Files created and/or modified in SP Document Library are published using an Azure Web App site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thought us ftp connector create the copy to app folder could be realized.

What you should be cared of is what you get from deployment center is a FTPs Endpoint. You could just delete the "s" and "/site/wwwroot" then get the FTP Endpoint. Like this `ftps://******.ftp.p.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot` after change it would be like `ftp://*****.ftp.p.azurewebsites.windows.net` then the ftp connection will could be created.

And here is the pic about the Logic App flow.

[image]

The file I create will be stored in `wwwroot`, you could choose the App folder to store. And I tested my logic app, it works well.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: If my answer works, you could mark my answer. Thanks!